# Nesting formulas not working as expected Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, nested, match, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I am trying to nest the following two formulas, both work.

cell AO2 = Bob,  cell AP2 = Judy

`=TEXTJOIN(\"|\", True, AO2, AP2) = Bob|Judy`

`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("*sumAppTags",Elements!A1:BB1,0),4),1,"") = Column Index AO`

If I try:

`=TEXTJOIN("|", True, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("*sumAppTags",Elements!A1:BB1,0),4),1,"")&2, AP2)`

I get: `AO2|Judy`

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, 
 MATCH("*sumAppTags", Elements!A1:BB1, 0), 4), 1, )&2), AP2)
```

Comment: Thank you Player0, that did answer my question as I wrote it. but if I copy down I get an error as the `2` does not increment. Is there a way to make this dynamic so if I copy down the 2 gets incremented by 1 for each row that the formula is copied down. Thank you

Comment: I got it based on your solution `=TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, 
 MATCH("*sumAppTags", Elements!$A$1:$BB$1, 0), 4), 1, )&ROW(AO2)), AP2)` Thanks again